# multiple caddy/frankenphp apps in local docker

Tags: php, docker, caddy

I'm using https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker Symfony images with caddy and frankephp for my app, but now I need to add another app with the same image, so to do so I considered moving docker-compose to one level higher, like

```
backend/
   compose.yaml
   catalog/
   admin/
```

now my compose file looks like this:

```
services:
  catalog:
    image: ${IMAGES_PREFIX:-}app-php
    build:
      context: ./catalog
      target: frankenphp_dev
    volumes:
      - ./catalog:/app
      - ./catalog/frankenphp/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile:ro
      - ./catalog/frankenphp/conf.d/app.dev.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.dev.ini:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}, php:80
      TRUSTED_PROXIES: ${TRUSTED_PROXIES:-127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16}
      TRUSTED_HOSTS: ^${SERVER_NAME:-example\.com|localhost}|php$$
      # Run "composer require symfony/orm-pack" to install and configure Doctrine ORM
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER:-app}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}@database:5432/${POSTGRES_DB:-app}?serverVersion=${POSTGRES_VERSION:-15}&charset=${POSTGRES_CHARSET:-utf8}
      # The two next lines can be removed after initial installation
      SYMFONY_VERSION: ${SYMFONY_VERSION:-}
      STABILITY: ${STABILITY:-stable}
    volumes:
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: 8001
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: 441
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: 441
        protocol: udp

  admin:
    image: ${IMAGES_PREFIX:-}app-php
    build:
      context: ./admin
      target: frankenphp_dev
    volumes:
      - ./admin:/app
      - ./admin/frankenphp/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile:ro
      - ./admin/frankenphp/conf.d/app.dev.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.dev.ini:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}, php:80
      TRUSTED_PROXIES: ${TRUSTED_PROXIES:-127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16}
      TRUSTED_HOSTS: ^${SERVER_NAME:-example\.com|localhost}|php$$
      # Run "composer require symfony/orm-pack" to install and configure Doctrine ORM
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER:-app}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}@database:5432/${POSTGRES_DB:-app}?serverVersion=${POSTGRES_VERSION:-15}&charset=${POSTGRES_CHARSET:-utf8}
      SYMFONY_VERSION: ${SYMFONY_VERSION:-}
      STABILITY: ${STABILITY:-stable}
    volumes:
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: 8002
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: 442
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: 442
        protocol: udp
  database:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-app}
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
  database_data:
```

as you can see I specified different ports for each app 8001 and 8002 and different https ports 441 and 442.

In both app I have identical Caddyfile:

```
{
    {$CADDY_GLOBAL_OPTIONS}

    frankenphp {
        {$FRANKENPHP_CONFIG}
    }

    order vulcain after reverse_proxy
    order php_server before file_server
}

{$CADDY_EXTRA_CONFIG}

{$SERVER_NAME:localhost} {
    log {
        format filter {
            wrap console
            fields {
                uri query {
                    replace authorization REDACTED
                }
            }
        }
    }

    root * /app/public
    encode zstd gzip

    vulcain
    {$CADDY_SERVER_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
    header ?Permissions-Policy "browsing-topics=()"
    php_server
}
```

I am able to run containers by running `docker-compose up -d` but I'm not able to open app URLs, for example, `localhost:8001/filters`, I'm getting the error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:443`
but when only one app is running all good.

I'm new to Caddy, but I think I need to set up some rever-proxy on top of my apps?

Comment: Can you add logs from the containers? What do you mean by `when only one app is running` you removed one of the service form the `compose.yaml` file?

Comment: You have the same `image: ${IMAGES_PREFIX:-}app-php` for both app but context is build from two different source, so they can override each other, but I'm not sure I just use different names when image is built from a different context